# Spark app returns IOException, "Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

My Versions:

- spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7,
- kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0,
- apache-cassandra-3.9.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaSparkStreaming").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

val topicpMap = "mytopic".split(",").map((_, 1.toInt)).toMap

val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "sparkgroup", topicpMap).map(_._2)

lines.map(line => { val arr = line.split(","); (arr(0),arr(1),arr(2),arr(3),arr(4)) }).saveToCassandra("sparkdata", "cust_data", SomeColumns("fname", "lname","url","product","cnt"))
```

I tried to run this command but i got the error :

```
lines.map(line => { val arr = line.split(","); (arr(0),arr(1),arr(2),arr(3),arr(4)) }).saveToCassandra("sparkdata", "cust_data", SomeColumns("fname", "lname","url","product","cnt"))
```

the error i am getting:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:168)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:32)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.syncAcquire(RefCountedCache.scala:69)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:57)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:79)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:122)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:330)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.tableFromCassandra(Schema.scala:350)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:336)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions.saveToCassandra(DStreamFunctions.scala:53)
  ... 58 elided
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
  at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
  at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1483)
  at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:399)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:161)
  ... 70 more
```

please anybody pointout my error to resolve?

Comment: what's the output of `nodetool status` (from the actual C* node that you're trying to connect) and `curl -v telnet://127.0.0.1:9042` (from where you're running the spark cassandra connector based program) commands?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you running versions of software that are over 5+ years old? (Spark and Kafka)... Spark-Streaming has been deprecated for several years. Use Structured Streaming instead, which the datastax connector should also be using

Comment: i had been seen one youtube channel he was using the same versions as i mentioned above but i got the error.could you help me to resolve this error

Comment: @OneCricketeer first i thanks to you!! and my commands all are executed but my data was not stored in cassandra database.i just type the sample data in kafka producer console it also received in kafka consumer console but the data was not stored in cassandra db.  kindly please help me bro to resolve this error

Comment: Personally, I'd start at the [documentation](https://www.datastax.com/dev/kafka) rather than old YouTube videos. If you use the Kafka Connector there, you don't need to run Spark code at all

Answer (score 0):

A NoHostAvailableException means the connection cannot be established. That's a lower layer, so before trying any authentication. Thus, your problem is connectivity. Here are some things to check:

1. Are you sure 9042 is the correct port? Did you change the default native port?
2. Is there a firewall? This seems highly unlikely because you're trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:9042.
3. Did you verify that Cassandra is listening on port 9042 (netstat) and that the port is open t

Either way, it's a connectivity issue.

Comment: i am sorry brother actually i am new to spark.i am sure my port is 9042 and open native connection is 127.0.0.1 when i saw in the cassandra.yaml file.                                            kindly help me brother to solve this error.i will give you my full cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the other question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76533720/), it looks like you've kicked off your Spark application while Cassandra is still down leading to the `NoHostAvailableException`.

You need to make sure that Cassandra is operational before you run any applications or clients that connect to it.

Check the Cassandra `system.log` to monitor the progress of the startup sequence. When you see a log entry that looks like this:

```
... Starting listening for clients ...
```

then you know that Cassandra started up successfully and is ready to accept client requests. Cheers!