# Getting connection error with cqlsh, "Unable to connect to any servers"

Tags: cassandra

my cassandra version:
apache-cassandra3.9

`bin/cqlsh`

when i run the above command, i am getting the error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

sometimes `bin/cqlsh` command works for me when i run the new window. every first time i tried to enter into the cassandra shell but that command does not work but when i tried 3 or 4 more time it will work.

i have one more issue. i am doing spark end to end streaming. i got one error. my all commands are executed but the data did not get stored into my cassandra database. in my first question i given my all information about spark streaming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you described indicates that the Cassandra instance you're attempting to connect to is not operational yet.

When you start Cassandra, it has to go through some initialisation tasks which can take anywhere from 20-25 seconds to several minutes depending on how much data there is on the node and its state from the last shutdown.

I recommend you check the Cassandra `system.log` to monitor the progress of the startup sequence. When you see a log entry that looks like this:

```
... Starting listening for clients ...
```

then you know that Cassandra started up successfully and is ready to accept client requests. Cheers!

Comment: thanks you so much bro!!now its working.  i am a beginner, i have one more doubt bro actually i am doing spark streaming with kafka and cassadra. but the data didnot stored in my cassandra . my code and my spark kafks versions i mentioned my first question. kindly please help me bro